# Get all li data-val in an ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get the data-val of a li when it has a link inside, could you help me to fix it?

li example:

```
<li data-val="Lima 2">Lima [T:19ºC H:82%]<a href="#" onclick="if(confirm('Remover?')){parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)}"><span style="float:right;"><b>[X]</b></span></a>
</li>
```

Javascript

```
$("#cup").on("click", function () {
$('.clista').each(function () {
    var cidades = [];
    var cidade = '';
    $(this).find('li').each(function () {
        var current = $(this);
        if (current.children().size() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        cidade += $(this).attr('data-val');
        alert(cidade);
    });
    cidades.push(cidade);
});
```

});

Could you check the script: http://jsfiddle.net/fabiobraglin/rcheaowx/8/

Tks a lot!

Comment: First of all, you are leaving out important information here. Where is #cup? Where is clista? Please update your post with all the required html.

Comment: I'm not able to add all html code... I don't know why... but you can check at JDFIDDLE link... if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your `alert` outside of the `each` function. And you shouldn't check for children, that's why you don;t get the result you want.

```
$('.clista').each(function () {
    var cidades = [];
    var cidade = '';
    $(this).find('li').each(function () {


        cidade += $(this).attr('data-val');

    });
    alert(cidade);
    cidades.push(cidade);
});
```

Comment: Hi, could you help me with a new problem at this script? jsfiddle.net/fabiobraglin/rcheaowx/11 When click in Update, sometimes the result is empty... I believe this is bacause need some time to get JSON data...

Comment: @FábioBraglin I've updated your code. You need to call your function when the result will be got from getJson. http://jsfiddle.net/rcheaowx/12/

Comment: Hello dude... I don't know why, but the script just update the last one... could you help me?? Sorry for this, I don't have the knowledge required... http://jsfiddle.net/fabiobraglin/rcheaowx/21/ I really appreciate your help! tks

Answer (score 0):

Since you have put an if block which returns true if li has children. I don't know what are you trying to accomplish by doing so. However, that if check becomes true and function exits by returning true. If you remove that return statement or remove complete if block, your update function will work fine. Try this. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   $("#cup").on("click", function () {
        var   cidades = new Array();
        $('.clista li').each(function () {
         cidades.push($(this).data('val'));
            });

        alert(cidades);
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rcheaowx/9/

Answer (score 0):

to get all the data-val  just remove the below code section

`if (current.children().size() > 0) {
            return true;
        }`